# Python Flask catch IntegrityError doesnt work

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a form where a user can upload one or multiple images via multiselect. These images belong to a room. Images are stored on the server in a static folder. In the database I save then the path to the image in the "pfad" attribute". I assigned to the `pfad` attribute `unique=True` because every image should be identified, because it is possible that different users could name an image the same way.

In my models.py (SQLalchemy) there is a `Bild` Class, this is the attribute:

```
pfad = Column(Text, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

If the images do not have the same name everything works fine, but in case an IntegrityError would be thrown my code does not handle it. My idea was: If an IntegrityError occurs I would split the filename and add a number to it, so `pfad` would be a different one:

I have the image `fun.jpg` in my static folder and someone uploads an other image called `fun.jpg` -> my code should "fun" + "1." + "jpg" -> `fun1.jpg` and then save it. But I still get IntegrityErrors.

Thats how I do it:

```
images = request.files.getlist("bild")   
if new_zimmer:
            db_session.add(new_zimmer)
            db_session.commit()

            for img in images:
                filename = secure_filename(img.filename)
                try:
                    print "file existiert nicht"
                    img.save(UPLOAD_FOLDER + filename)
                    new_bild = Bild(pfad=filename, zimmer_id=new_zimmer.id)
                    db_session.add(new_bild)

                except IntegrityError:
                    print "file existiert"
                    filename_list = filename.split(".")
                    new_filename = filename_list[0] + "1." + filename_list[1]
                    img.save(UPLOAD_FOLDER + new_filename)
                    new_bild = Bild(pfad=new_filename, zimmer_id=new_zimmer.id)
                    db_session.add(new_bild)

                db_session.commit()
```

The relevant part beginns at `for img in images`. I tried to provide only relevant code pieces. Hoope someone can help me to handle this issue. Thanks

**EDIT:**

if I move `db_session.commit()` up I get this Error:

```
try:
                print "file existiert nicht"
                img.save(UPLOAD_FOLDER + filename)
                new_bild = Bild(pfad=filename, zimmer_id=new_zimmer.id)
                db_session.add(new_bild)
                db_session.commit()


            #else:
            except IntegrityError:
                print "file existiert"
                filename_list = filename.split(".")
                new_filename = filename_list[0] + "1." + filename_list[1]
                img.save(UPLOAD_FOLDER + new_filename)
                new_bild = Bild(pfad=new_filename, zimmer_id=new_zimmer.id)
                db_session.add(new_bild)
                db_session.commit()
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError
InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) column pfad is not unique [SQL: u'INSERT INTO bilder (pfad, zimmer_id) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: ('zimmer2_01.jpg', 11)]
```

Comment: shouldn't you be commiting right after db_session.add(new_blind)?

Comment: I also tried it, but still the same error

Comment: InvalidRequest because of IntegrityError

Comment: in which case you can InvalidRequest?

Comment: The mistake in my humble opinion is that you are waiting for the exception to be raised, why don't just check it before with an if statement.

Comment: I have also a versiob with an if statement which actually works fine if I would leave out "unique=True" it even renames the files and saves them with the number added, but somehow if "unique=True" it still gives me IntegrityError, I am just trying to understand why. If nobody gets it, I just remove the "unique=True" and use the if statement

Comment: is this on github?

Comment: no, I am making this localy and havent it uploaded anywhere yet.

Comment: Okay, I had to renew the session, it went first of all into the try block and after it failed I had to add at the beginning of the except block: `db_session.remove()` now it works switching into the right field, but I have an other Error DetachedInstanceError: Instance <Zimmer at 0x3556c50> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed --- But I can continue to work now

Comment: Did you actually check the entries in the db? It looks like it's telling you that you already have that entry in the db with that name. As @wind85 notes, you're better checking it exists and renaming than catching the exception -- what if you have multiple zimmer2.jpg entries, it'll stop renaming after the first exception, and then crash in the except clause.

Comment: Yeah, I already solved it, checking with if ... else ... while. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code include the definition of the Integrity Error?

This may help:
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError